# If you are starting to tie your own fly fishing flies, what types would be the easiest to start with?

Tags: diy, fly-fishing, fly-tying

The are two main types of fly fishing flies, wet (sink underneath) and dry (float on top).

If one were trying to learn how to how tie the flies yourself instead of buying them, **would one type be easier to start with** rather than the other?

Comment: Larger flies, either wet or dry, would be the best to start with.  Personally, I think wet flies are easier because I don't like messing with the hair on many types of dry flies.

Comment: @wanderweeer I adjusted the question, you should make that answer

Answer (score 2):

The fly patterns used in modern european nymphing are purposefully simple and effective. The philosophy behind these patterns is to suggest the shape of the insect instead of trying to perfectly match the hatch, and this makes them very versatile as well.

Patterns like the tungsten torpedo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyXKOhM9wY0

Or the tungsten surveyor:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaQvmSgb4eo

Are extremely easy to tie and very effective.

For dries, the CDC and elk:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siubcX93zjQ

And the F-fly:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zusbn891Gdk

Are very simple and do a great job suggesting caddis and mayflies of various types when tied in different sizes and colours.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fly to tie is probably an egg pattern. The fly requires a hook, high tensile thread, head glue and either a marker or a small amount of flash. This fly may take ~20 minutes the first time tied and can take <5 minutes after tying ~5 flies. It’s a great fly to begin with as you do not need to worry about a multitude of materials and managing sometimes fragile feathers.